# Force WPF ListBox to contain exactly x elements

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to force a ListBox to display an even amount of elements - that is, if there is over 10 elements, I want it to display *exactly* 10 elements, and make the others available by scrolling. The only example I know is the Visual Studio intellisense popup.

I don't want to display fractions of items, since it looks ugly.

I've tried setting the height to `10 * item height`, and accounting for Border, Margin and Padding, but there are other factors - such that the actual Border has a 1 pixel padding. Even accounting for that the size is off by a few pixels. This solution is just waiting to blow up.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Just an idea, but how about "paging" the results into a temporary collection you bind to, and then on scroll altering the "paged" collection?

Comment: @Tejs Wouldn't the WPF paging utility also display that same fractional item? Something like 'Oh, so there is 10.21 items visible - I'll load 11 then'? I still want to display the scroll bars with the correct amount of 'scroll area' available,

Comment: Stuff like this can be fixed in version 2 :P

Answer (score 0):

Do it using a behavior.

Behaviors allow you to, in Xaml, add functionality to controls.  Here's a tutorial: [Behaviors Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html)

To give you an idea of what this would look like in code:

Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <i:Interactions.Behaviors>
        <b:TenItemsInViewBehavior/>
    </i:Interactions.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

Code:

```
public class TenItemsInViewBehavior:Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        //AssociatedObject is the ListView object - you can bind to its events
        this.AssociatedObject. SelectionChanged+=CheckIfOnTenthItem;       
    }
    private void CheckIfOnTenthItem(object sender, eventargs e)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

What happens is that the Behavior binds to the control and notifies you with the OnAttached() method.  When this happens you'll find that a property on the Behavior called "AssociatedObject" is populated with your control.  You can now bind to the control, its data, events, etc and manipulate it as you want.

One way of doing what you want would be to take the data from the Listbox and store it in the behavior and then just rebind the first 10 records.  Once the user had scrolled to the 10th you could start adding new items to the list (or manipulating the list as you want).

To get behaviors you need to download Expression Blend and grab the System.Windows.Interactivity dll.  Once you have it you can uninstall Blend.

Behaviors are a great way of adding extra functionality to a control in a modular and consistent way.